# What tool can get two 1x2 plates apart without damaging them?

Tags: tools, disassembly

Teeth and pliers tend to leave unsightly marks on the bricks.

Fingernails don't work too well.

What tool do you recommend to separate them?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could try the great brick separator. Designed for this specific purpose, it's probably your best bet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perfect image...

Answer (score 21):

I normally use two big bricks: one on the top and one at the bottom.  Then you push down while rotating.

Answer (score 21):

Or you could use, guess what, a **new** brick separator:

[image: 96874 — Human Tool, Brick and Axle Separator]

(http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=96874)

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the Brick Separator, there are some parts that work well for this

[image: brick separator alternative]

[Original here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/retracile/5377762249/).

Answer (score 15):

There's the great LEGO Brick Separator that can be bought in the [LEGO Online Shop](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Brick-Separator-630):

[image: Brick Separator]

I love this thing. It's just great if you want to take care of your nails and teeth.

Comment: As of now it has been replaced with a new variation.

Answer (score 8):

I use a fingernail most times,  or a guitar pick if the bricks are stuck too firmly.

Answer (score 6):

I (and my sons) use a plastic knife designed for children. We found ours in IKEA (larger bricks for houses)

I have also used [this lego tool](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92585) with moderate success

Answer (score 4):

A flat-style staple remover (as opposed to the jaws style) does well to maintain the surface of a stuck brickage. It also can be jimmied back and forth without much slippage.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try the Official [LEGO Brick Separator](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Brick-Separator-630). It would probably take a couple to work best on 1x2s though - one on the top, one on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this personally.

You could use two removal-tools (one to grab the top piece, one to grab the bottom piece)

Answer (score 0):

I usually put 1x2 bricks on the top and bottom of the stack of plates. This gives me enough leverage to break up the stack between the two plates. Afterwards, I remove the plates from the bricks.

Answer (score -1):

I've separated several plates (and bricks too) with a simple spring-based hair clip.

[image]

Comment: Ew! No metal bits!

Comment: Why not? It's been quite successful for me.

Comment: Because metal damages our precious ABS bits.