# How can I easily remove a jumper plate without a brick separator?

Tags: tools, disassembly

How can I easily remove a [jumper plate](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3794)?

[image: A Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud "Jumper" piece.]

I find it very difficult to remove this kind of brick with a brick separator.

Comment: There's actually a new Brick Separator coming that has an offset anti-stud that can be used for jumper plates.  Check out this Brothers-Brick article: http://www.brothers-brick.com/2011/10/05/new-brick-separator-adds-technic-axle-pusher-tile-removing-wedge/

Comment: @Grandpappy: That looks beautiful.

Comment: @Grandpappy They seem to be including the new brick separator in a few sets now - especially larger ones.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A 1x1x5 brick has enough leverage to remove most jumper plates. Apply pressure to the top of the brick and pull or push away from the length of the jumper plate.

[image]

Even a 1x1 brick works in certain cramped places, although It doesn't provide as much leverage.

Comment: If I had a big enough lever I could move the world.  Clever!

Answer (score 14):

I'll try to show how I'd do this using a [2×12 plate](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2445) (or something similar). Imagine you're looking at it from the side:

```
      n_n_n_n_n_n_n_n_n_n_n_n_ --> Pull     | narrow, long plate
     _n_                                    | jumper plate
_n_n_n_n_n_n_                               | baseplate
```

`n` = stud

Just attach a plate or brick to the top of the jumper and push it to the side so it will tip over.

*PS: I hope the ASCII-art makes clear what I tried to explain - I don't have a LEGO-designer here at work*

Comment: I like this idea, considering how common this brick is. I'd have to try it for myself thought to see how well it works, especialy in tight spaces.

Comment: for me this works better because you only need a bit pressure and can pull very easy. when using a pillar like you suggested, you'll have to push relatively hard to avoid to slip of.

Comment: You don't have to push hard but it helps.

Comment: That ascii-art is surprisingly simple and efficient. As for the answer, sometimes adding a brick opposite the your 2x12 plate helps too, as that brick will stay in place and you can lift the 2x12 plate as well as pulling it, producing a lever effect too.

Answer (score 7):

Use the new Jumper Tile 2.0 instead! Easier to remove! Comes in many<sup>1</sup> colors<sup>2</sup>! Advanced features<sup>3</sup>! Comes in many colours<sup>4</sup>! Lighter than the old, clumsy version!

Don't wait, contact your closest LEGO reseller to upgrade your collection of obsolete jumpers to new, shiny ones!

<sup>1. Three.</sup>
<sup>2. U.S. version only.</sup>
<sup>3. The same as Jumper 1.0, plus Easier removal</sup>
<sup>4. U.K. version only.</sup>

---

Seriously though, LEGO just added a groove on jumpers, see the difference:

[image: 3794b — Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove (Jumper)]

Which admittedly doesn't help you right now, but at least you can take comfort in knowing LEGO adressed the issue somehow.

Comment: My first inclination with this question was "I swear there's a groove on the bottom..." but then I checked the nearest model and there wasn't. I guess this is why.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who noticed this change.

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Ambo100 I didn't think it would, honestly. If I had wanted to answer seriously, it would just have been a slightly different take on oezi's answer, which I think is the easiest.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [new brick separator](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/09/lego-brick-separator-new-version/):

[image: Brick separator]

...when it becomes available.

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: It looks like it performs just as well as the old brick separator would with jumper plates. Until it's released and we know for sure that it works it's not viable for now.

Comment: @Ambo100: There have are already been a few on Bricklink, and they have been specifically designed with this task in mind. ut you're right, of course: we won't know for sure until someone publishes their experiences. Let's hope they're good, and that this tool lives up to its promise.

Comment: It's now [available for sale](http://shop.lego.com/en-DK/Brick-Separator-630?_requestid=16994600) on the online shop.

Answer (score 2):

Place a regular 1x2 plate on top of it (the hollow stud of the jumper plate fits around the post in the bottom of the 1x2), and apply lateral force to the combination. They should come off together. Then rotate the two to separate them from each other.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few parts that can be used in place of a brick separator
[image: brick separator alternative]

This won't help with jumper plates in the middle of baseplates, but can be useful in other situations.

[Original here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/retracile/5377762249/).

Comment: Somehow, I'm not sure that helps with tiles on a baseplate. See also my comment on your [other similar answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/474)

Comment: Sure, in the middle of a baseplate this wouldn't help.  But there is nothing in the question about baseplates.