# How should I model a Heroica scale castle bedroom?

Tags: building, lego-games, micro-scale, heroica

My son has requested that we add a bedroom to our Heroica castle. I'm looking for some advice on the creation of the bed area.

The Microfig characters are 1x1x2, and the rooms are generally designed to sit on a 6x6 or 8x8 plate, and will have path elements (Tile 2x2 with 1 stud [Part:87580]) on it for the characters and treasure to be placed.

Comment: I was wondering about the path elements. It's more or less obvious where they mist be placed, but are there specific guidelines or rules as to how many you must place on a 6x6 or 8x8 plate? On a 6x6 plate for example, not all available slots must be filled, but is just 2 OK? What about just one? 8x8 plates seem to be for boss monsters, does that imply more path tiles need to be present? (I guess I'll need to buy one of these)

Comment: No guidelines at all, but none of the official maps have two paths coming off the same side - so 1-4 total. How many you use is mostly about how many branches you want in the map.

Comment: @Joubarc Nope, no real guidelines, it can be anything from a strip of paths down one side, an "L" shape or a block of 4 in the centre: http://heroica.lego.com/en-us/Products/Default.aspx#3860 I've also just noticed that for more room, they sometimes use a Tile 1x2 with 1 stud length-ways (see the waterfall room here: http://heroica.lego.com/en-us/Products/Default.aspx#3857)

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed that bridge in Draida Bay and thought it was a nice touch - creating some illusion of danger and all. By The way, it also looks quite close to what I would have in mind for a bed: 2 1x1 round plates, then a 1x2 white tile, or 1x1 white tile with 1x1 cheese slope for the pillow. Anyway, thanks for the link, I hadn't realized there was a pdf with the rules there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my attempt on a 6x6 plate. I built only one wall for the image clarity, but maybe you'd prefer one opposite wall as well.

If you don't have the [tile with the pillow](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx38), replace it with a 1 x 2 slope or something.

[image]
Construction details if it's not clear enough:

[image: Heroica castle bedroom - detail]

Comment: Don't worry, I've got the tile with the pack ;)

Comment: @Joubarc, 64647 is included with my Heroica part pack - from an unapproved version in the LDraw part library.

Comment: @Joe I hadn't looked in unapproved parts, thanks for the tip

Comment: Accepted purely for the four poster bed, (and the fact that it feels wrong accepting my own answer ;))

Answer (score 5):

I went with the following set up - note that as the microfig is two bricks high, that means it's actually three studs long:

[image: Castle Bedroom with bedside candle]
Castle Bedroom with bedside candle

[image: LDraw Castle Bedroom with bedside candle]
Castle Bedroom with bedside candle (LDraw)

Comment: Nice to see both the LDraw rendering **and** a picture. And you're right, a 1x3 bed is more suitable for microfigs. But hey, my own bed is too short for me, so no reason they wouldn't suffer the same fate.

Comment: Cheers, we made for a quick game this evening ;)

Comment: So quick that you didn't even take the time to push the parts on the plate properly, or were you afraid you wouldn't be able to [remove the jumper easily](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/443)? ;)