# How can I remove a rubber band from a pulley?

Tags: technic, mindstorms, disassembly, rubber-bands

We have a pulley and a bunch of rubber bands:

[image: The pulley and the rubber band.]

We don't know that part numbers, but they all were part of a Mindstorms (RCX 2.0) set.  My son was trying use the pulley and band to transfer power to another pulley.  But it didn't work out that way:

[image: The pulley and the rubber band.]

Now the band doesn't slip off of the pulley.  We figure we can cut it off, but we'd kinda like to save the band if at all possible.

Have you ever run across this sort of problem?  Do you have any suggestions for removing the rubber band without destroying it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I've said before in [another answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1186/132), I find the [#92585 Crowbar](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92585) is the most versatile and is especially good at removing rubber bands from the [#3736 (Technic, Steering Pulley Large)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3736) and the [#4185 (Technic, Wedge Belt Wheel)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4185) elements.

Don't use any sharp/metallic objects like a screwdriver or a pen knife as you may scratch the brick or sever the rubber band.

Comment: We did manage to get the band off with the [#400626 Screwdriver/Spanner](http://www.brickset.com/parts/?part=400626) which has a broad sharp edge.  It took a little prying to dig it between the rim and band, but once I got under it, the band popped right out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to successfully get that size band off of that pulley using this brick separator:

[image]

I slid the sharp end in between the band and the pulley then worked it under the band and was able to pull the band off without damaging either part. If you don't have a brick separator handy, you can probably use a pointy minifig utensil such as a sword instead. I wouldn't recommend using metal tool such as a screwdriver or knife as this could easily cut the band as you try to remove it.

Good luck!

Comment: And if that doesn't work, unbit nails should do the trick

Comment: My son has the old brick separator which doesn't have a sharp end.  He tried a spear point, which really seemed promising.  I managed to pry it off with a crowbar similar to what Ambo100 [suggested](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2291/2866), however.