# A piece with no place in Heartlake Stables

Tags: sets, friends

I recently bought this set for my niece for her birthday, when we were finished setting it up we noticed a larger orange piece that we couldn't find a place for but was in the set and in the back of the book where it outline what pieces there/how many of them. I just wondering for sure what the piece goes to?

Comment: Since you found the part in the booklet, could you specify its number as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll go and assume you're speaking about [4654448](http://www.brickset.com/parts/?part=4654448)

Answer (score 20):

That part is the new Brick Separator which LEGO includes in most bigger sets:

[image: 4654448 - Brick Separator]

It's not part of the construction itself, but is a tool to allow you to easily disassemble constructions. You can compare it with the older version in [this question on how to separate 1x2 plates](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6/99).

Comment: Oooh, I hadn't seen the new one. I like the introduction of the + peg; I always had to fish out a + rod for pushing those out.

Comment: Page 3 of book 1 of the [instructions](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6029680.pdf).